# error: multiple types in one declaration in header define declaration

Tags: c++, libmemcached

[Github](https://github.com/Metaswitch/libmemcached-upstream)
In order to compile a project (sprout), I have to compile libmemcached first. During compilation it generates a `config.h` file, which is from `config.ac` I think. However, this `config.h` causes problem:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/libmemcached'
  CXX      libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo
In file included from ./libhashkit/common.h:40:0,
                 from libhashkit/aes.cc:38:
./config.h:632:20: error: multiple types in one declaration
 #define off_t long int
                    ^
./config.h:632:20: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
./config.h:658:17: error: multiple types in one declaration
 #define ssize_t int
                 ^
./config.h:658:17: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
./config.h:635:15: error: multiple types in one declaration
 #define pid_t int
               ^
./config.h:635:15: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
make[1]: *** [libhashkit/libhashkit_libhashkit_la-aes.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/libmemcached'
```

This is config.h:

```
628 /* Define to rpl_malloc if the replacement function should be used. */
629 #define malloc rpl_malloc
630
631 /* Define to `long int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
632 #define off_t long int
633
634 /* Define to `int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
635 #define pid_t int
636
637 /* Define to rpl_realloc if the replacement function should be used. */
638 #define realloc rpl_realloc
657 /* Define to `int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
658 #define ssize_t int
```

It does not meet this problem in Ubuntu:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

It has this problem in CentOS：

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)
```

UPDATE：
as @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. suggested, I digged deeper.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define off_t long int
int main() {
   int a = 1;
   int b = a++;
   return 10;
}
```

above code compiles, and `g++ -E -P` results OK1
Then I exchange `include` and `define` declaration:

```
#define off_t long int
#include <stdio.h>
```

above code does not compile, and `g++ -E -P` results ERROR
Then I deleted `define` decalration, it compiles again, and results OK2.

```
diff OK1 ERROR
```

output:

```
173c173
< typedef __off_t off_t;
---
> typedef __off_t long int;
```

```
diff OK1 OK2
```

output empty (OK1 and OK2 are the same).
Then I released that VIM marked `off_t` the same color as `long` or `int`. Maybe `off_t` is a reserved keyword?  Then I changed `off_t` with `offt`:

```
#define offt long int
#include <stdio.h>
```

it compiles again.

Comment: This message doesn't make a lot of sense. If you try to compile a file that only contains one line `#define ssize_t int`, do you have this error? How about a file that only has `#include "config.h"`?

Comment: The error is actually in how these macros are used. See `from libhashkit/aes.cc:38:` in the message? That's the point most likely.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I just looked at that line. It is an #include directive. `#include <libhashkit/common.h>`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I tried, it compiles. I also tried a file with `#include "config.h"`, it compiles too.

Comment: This is very strange. Try running `g++ -E -P libhashkit/aes.cc`, capturing the output, and compiling it. What errors do you get?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. strange indeed. I just found that common.h causes problem, only if it is followed by any other header file. Haven't given up yeet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration script that produces `config.h` is faulty.

```
631 /* Define to `long int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
632 #define off_t long int
```

This would be fine if `off_t` was't defined anywhere on your system. But it is defined and used by the system headers, most likely like this:

```
typedef long int __off_t;
typedef __off_t off_t;
```

The `#define` wreaks these definitions, making them syntactically invalid.

The simplest way to fix the problem is to manually remove the offending `#define`s from `config.h` and make sure `sys/types.h` is included.

Comment: Is there a JIRA for libmemcached, I did not find it on GitHub, otherwise, I would like to report this as a BUG.